# Global and local indexing approach on a range partitioned table

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

We currently join multiple range partitioned tables and perform aggregation on the metrics collected from devices. The tables below are range partitioned where the `date` column is the partition key.

```
Table A

| device | date       | kpi_a |
|--------|------------|-------|
| a      | 2020-08-11 | 5     |
| b      | 2020-08-10 | 3     |


Table B

| device | date       | kpi_b |
|--------|------------|-------|
| a      | 2020-08-11 | 1     |
| b      | 2020-08-10 | 9     |
```

Lets say that we want to run a (pseudo) query such that:

```
select device, date, kpi_a + kpi_b as kpi_x
from table_a join table_b on date and device 
group by date, device
```

When a table in Oracle is range partitioned on date (daily) does it help to have a global non unique index in the same date (partition key) column?

As a broader question what is a good way to index these two (date) range partitioned tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither kind of index is likely to help a query that has no predicates. Even the partitioning is not likely to help with a query that selects and joins almost all rows from two tables.

Indexing is useful for selecting a small percentage of data from a table - walking a b-tree to retrieve one row is a very fast operation regardless of the size of the table. But if you have to traverse the index for every row, that's much more work than simply reading the whole table.

Partitioning is useful for selecting a large percentage of data from a table - if the table is broken into multiple physical segments then only the relevant segment needs to be read. But if the query must read every row, then splitting the table into pieces just makes more work, as there will be more overhead for the extra segments. (Although if you have identical partitioning between tables, and are using parallelism, then you may be able to see advantages from partition-wise joins.)

Indexing and partitioning are not necessarily helpful for *combining* data quickly - they're more suited for quickly *eliminating* unnecessary data. But if all the data from the tables is used, there's no point in those extra data structures.

Usually, the choice between a global or local index depends on what predicates are involved with your queries. If the queries will almost always be able to partition prune, then using a smaller local index will be better. If the queries are not able to partition prune, then it's better to read from one large global index instead of many small local indexes.